# php current time and mysql tables time

Tags: php

I have a store site where I am using the opening and closing time of the store and it is working fine like if the opening time is 08:00 am and closing time is 09:00 pm.
But it is not working if the opening time is 11:30 am and closing time is 04:00 am.
My code is below:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuwait");
$rest_oc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timing WHERE sr_id = '".$rm_id."'");
while ($oc  = mysql_fetch_array($rest_oc)) {
    $timo   =   $oc['open'];
    $timc   =   $oc['close'];
    $ptime  =   date("h:i a");

    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $ptime);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $timo);
    $date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $timc);

    if ($date3 < $date2) {
    $date3->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

    if ($date1 >= $date2 && $date1 <= $date3) {
    ?>
        <div class="tagR">
            <img src="images/openN.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
<?php }else{ ?>
        <div class="tagR">
            <img src="images/closed.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: It's because the date doesn't change, so 4am will always be before 11:30am. You may want to see if closing is before opening, and if so, add a day to closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that won't work because 4am is obviously before 11:30am if all you are using is time. Add this before your if condition

```
if ($date1 < $date2) {
    $date2->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
} else {
    if ($date3 < $date2) {
        $date3->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}
```

Comment: well it was working that time but now suddenly its stopped working... i have updated my code please check... @georaldc

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is your if condition not being satisfied again?

Comment: yes its showing CLOSED... the open time is 11:30am and closing time is 3:30am.. but as per the updated code its still showing me CLOSED

Comment: It's because of your timezone change. It's 6/16 2AM in Kuwait right now. The dates you are comparing that to are 6/16 11:30AM and 6/17 3:30 AM with my previous answer. See my updated answer

Comment: yes working now fine thanks alot again and sorry for disturbance